# Generate sequence using recursion

Tags: c++, recursion

I'm trying to return 1 2 5 9 16 27 ... where we get 9 = 5 + (5-2) + (2-1), 16 = 9 + (9-5) + (5-2), and so on. I'm returning it because I need to use it in another function. I'm still getting the hang of recursion so I cannot for the life of me figure out how to do this correctly. Here's what I've tried so far:

```
int sequence(int n)
{
    if(n<=2) return n;
    else if(n==3) return 5;
    return sequence(n-1)+((sequence(n-1)-sequence(n-2))+((sequence(n-2)-sequence(n-3))));
}
```

Edit: I intended this to return a single number, the first 3 elements are given.

Comment: Do you expect this function to return a list of numbers, or a single number? "sequence" is ambiguous, and I don't see the introduction of any lists anywhere.

Comment: The order of evaluation isn't exactly specified here: `sequence(n-1)+((sequence(n-1)-sequence(n-2))+((sequence(n-2)+sequence(n-3))));`

Comment: This recursion you are describing and implementing is very heavy. In fact you only need the 3 previous numbers... so keep 3 variables and rotate the values there. If you are familiar with the fibonacci sequence you can see an example of what i am saying here http://www.programmingsimplified.com/cpp/source-code/fibonacci-series

Comment: @k_kaz i actually sort of modeled this after the fibonacci sequence, do you mean i should add 3 other parameters? or is there any way this could be done with just a single parameter?

Comment: It looks to me like the equation is following the form `a_{n+1} = a_{n} + (a_{n} - a_{n-1}) + (a_{n-1} - a_{n-2})` where `a_{n}` is the `nth` element in an array, the same array the answers are being stored in. If that's the case, while this could be done recursively, it would be simpler if it were an iterative loop (imo). If that's not the case, perhaps you could edit your post to contain the actual formula with variables, and how the first elements are derived (if not given)

Comment: Is recursion mandatory ?

Comment: @Penny i dont think it can be done with one or two paremeters. Maybe a an array or a vector of 3 elements with a rotation function whould be "simpler". That's just implementation. Just don't do this kind of recursion. Search fibonacci recursion complexity and you will see for yourself

Comment: @Jarod42 unfortunately, yes, I have to use recursion for this

Comment: @Penny what should for example `sequence(5)` return ?

Comment: @StackDanny sequence(5) would be 16.

Comment: @Penny because `5` means the 5th element of your sequence? Is that right?

Comment: @k_kaz but how should I do it if I absolutely have to go with recursion? I'm using this to try and understand recursion more.

Comment: @StackDanny yes, that's what it means

Comment: @Ped7g oh my gosh you're right! I've been debugging over and over for the past two hours, thank you very much!

Comment: @Penny after correcting `+` to `-`, your function correctly returns the values, is there still any problem you're facing?

Comment: Your code is now proper pure recursion way of doing that (as inefficient and practically unusable, as such pure recursion can be). So you got hang of recursion quite nicely, hang on debugging was missing. ;) ... what to do next time: if you have such complex formula, you may want to split it into local variables, like `int part1 = s(n-1); int part2 = s(n-1) - s(n-2); ...` and then verify in debugger the partial results are OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually wrote `sequence(n-2)+sequence(n-3)` instead of `sequence(n-2)-sequence(n-3)` (note the `+` sign instead of `-`)

If you see, you don't really need to call `sequence(n - 2)`, as `-sequence(n - 2)` and `+sequence(n - 2)` will cut out and leave the expression to just `sequence(n-1) + sequence(n-1) - sequence(n-3)`

And you're recursively calling with `n - 1` more than once, you can save some running time, call it only once and store the result in some variable and use it twice.

```
int sequence(int n)
{
    if(n<=2)
        return n;
    else if(n==3)
        return 5;
    int nMinus1 = sequence(n - 1);
    int nMinus3 = sequence(n - 3);
    return nMinus1 + nMinus1 - nMinus3;
}
```

See this implementation [live here](http://ideone.com/DiixNh).

---

But I would really recommend to use dynamic programming to store previous results and use them, as it will drastically reduce the running time. But if you have to use recursion and can't simply iterate to calculate the sequence, you can sure do something like this.

```
class SequenceGenerator{
private:
    static std::vector<int> results;
public:
    static int getNthInSequence(int n){
        if (results.size() == 0){
            results.push_back(0); // just to ignore the 0 index
            results.push_back(1);
            results.push_back(2);
            results.push_back(5);
        }
        if (n < results.size())
            return results.at(n);

        int nMinus1 = getNthInSequence(n - 1);
        int nMinus3 = getNthInSequence(n - 3);

        int result = nMinus1 + nMinus1 - nMinus3;
        results.push_back(result);
        return result;
    }
};

std::vector<int> SequenceGenerator::results;
```

[Here is a live demo](http://ideone.com/4wGs9d).

Answer (score 0):

Once you get the maths right, here's an implementation with minimal changes to yours

```
int sequence(int n)
{
    if(n<=2) return n;
    else if(n==3) return 5;

    return 2 * sequence(n-1) - sequence(n-3);
}
```

Comment: Note: the -nminus2 + nminus2 can be removed - thus doubling the speed

Answer (score -1):

```
f(n) = 2 * f(n - 1) - f(n - 2)
f(1) = 2
f(0) = 1
```

Please check this, it works for me:

```
#include <cstdio>

int suite_(int i){
    if(i == 0)
        return 1;

    if(i == 1)
        return 2;

    if(i == 2)
        return 5;

    return (2 * suite_(i -1) - suite_(i-3));
}

void main(){
    int j = 0;
    for (j=0; j < 10; ++j){
        printf("\nRes : %d",suite_(j));
    }
}
```

Results:

```
Res for 0: 1
Res for 1: 2
Res for 2: 5
Res for 3: 9
Res for 4: 16
Res for 5: 27
Res for 6: 45
Res for 7: 74
Res for 8: 121
Res for 9: 197
Res for 10: 320
Res for 11: 519
Res for 12: 841
Res for 13: 1362
Res for 14: 2205
Res for 15: 3569
Res for 16: 5776
Res for 17: 9347
Res for 18: 15125
Res for 19: 24474
```

Comment: I am sorry,

f(n) = 2 * f(n -1) - f(n-3)
f(1) = 2;
f(0) = 1 ;

Comment: This is both incorrect and not useful. The problem isn't with the definition but with the implementation (which turned out to just be a typo).